# How would I get whole page by eliminating some content from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have big page content but I want whole page with specified `id` content inside my body.

**Question:** inside `body` tag  `<table id="quotation">` and `jscode` should not be `removed`  **REST** everything should be removed from `body`

**Here s my page:**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- all other content to be removed -->

          other content to be removed 

  <!-- all other content to be removed -->

   <!-- should not be removed -->

         <table id="quotation">

          </table>

        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

  <!-- should not be removed -->
</body>
</html>
```

**I have tried soething like this:**

```
  var html = $('html').html();

  var body = $(html).find('body').not('#quotation').not('script').remove();

  console.log($(html).find('body').html(body).html());
```

**Above code give undefined**

Comment: `$(html).find('body').not('#quotation').not('script')` - this is not how `.not` works. You have selected all `body` elements (meaning elements with the _tag name_ `body`), and now you are filtering out those that do not have the id `quotation` or the tag name `script` ... since there are no such elements, this results in the exact same as just `$(html).find('body')` would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove all the element nodes using `*` and except the ones you want using `:not()` selector :

```
$('body *:not(#quotation):not(script)').remove();
```

Then the text nodes using :

```
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

```js
//Remove ELEMENT nodes
$('body *:not(#quotation):not(script)').remove();

//Remove TEXT nodes
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();

console.log($('body').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>

  other content to be removed
  <div>1111</div>
  <p></p>
  <span>AAAA</span>

  <table id="quotation">

  </table>

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

  <p></p>
</body>
```